# How to patch container env variable in deployment with kubectl?

Tags: json, kubernetes, kubectl, jsonpath

When I want to exctract the current value of some container env variabe I could use jsonpath with syntax like:

```
kubectl get pods -l component='somelabel' -n somenamespace -o \
jsonpath='{.items[*].spec.containers[*].env[?(@.name=="SOME_ENV_VARIABLE")].value}')
```

That will return me the value of env varialbe with the name `SOME_ENV_VARIABLE`. Pod section with container env variables in json will look like this:

```
            "spec": {
                "containers": [
                    {
                        "env": [
                            {
                                "name": "SOME_ENV_VARIABLE",
                                "value": "some_value"
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "ANOTHER_ENV_VARIABLE",
                                "value": "another_value"
                            }
                        ],
```

When I want to patch some value in my deployment I'm using commands with syntax like:

```
kubectl -n kube-system patch svc kubernetes-dashboard --type='json' -p="[{'op': 'replace', 'path': '/spec/ports/0/nodePort', 'value': $PORT}]"
```

But how can I patch a variable with `'op': 'replace'` in cases where I need to use expression like `env[?(@.name=="SOME_ENV_VARIABLE")]`? Which syntax I should use?

Answer (score 9):

Rather than [kubectl patch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#patching-resources) command, you can make use of [kubectl set env](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-env-em-) to update environment variable of k8s deployment.

```
envvalue=$(kubectl get pods -l component='somelabel' -n somenamespace -o jsonpath='{.items[*].spec.containers[*].env[?(@.name=="SOME_ENV_VARIABLE")].value}')
kubectl set env deployment/my-app-deploy op=$envvalue
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was very useful, tnx!

Answer (score 1):

Most of them haven't provide proper commands just use as simple as it is =>

```js
kubectl set env deployment/deploy_name APP_VERSION=value -n namespace
```

Answer (score -2):

- op: replace
  path: /spec/template/spec/containers/0/env/0/name
  value: YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME
- op: replace
  path: /spec/template/spec/containers/0/env/0/value
  value: YOUR_VARIABLE_VALUE

Comment: This just replaces the env item at index 0 rather than the item with the correct env var name.